# show form value in alert after click on button

Tags: javascript, html, button, alert

I am very new on HTML. I just trying to accept form value and want to show this value
in Alert.  I try following code but it didn't help me...
I know this is very easy question but i am newbie on HTML,JavaScript. I search but didn't find relative to my requirement....
Javascript function....

```
  function updateTxt(field1,field2)
  {  
    var field1 = document.getElementById(field1);  
    var field2 = document.getElementById(field2);  
    alert(field1,field2);

    }
```

HTML form

```
<input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="Search by keyword" class="search_input" >
<select name="select" id="select" class="input_list" >
          <option>Search jobs by category</option>
          <option>Business Sales Leadership Development Program</option>
          <option>Business Sales Solutions</option>
          <option>CTO</option>
          <option>Call Center</option></select>
 <input name="button" type="button" class="btn" value="Go" onClick="updateTxt(select,textfield)">
```

Please give me hint or direct me where i wrong...
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should call your function like this: updateTxt("select", "textfield"), so in your onclick: onclick='updateTxt("select", "textfield")'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change this code

```
<input name="button" type="button" class="btn" value="Go" onclick="updateTxt()">
```

and also this

```
     function updateTxt()
  {  
    var field1 = document.getElementById('textfield').value;  
    var field2 = document.getElementById('select').options[document.getElementById('select').selectedIndex].value;  
    alert(field1+'&'+field2);

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass strings into the `updateTxt` function. And `alert` can only take one parameter, so you'll have to concatenate the values of the fields, not the fields themselves. Your code would look like this:

JS:

```
function updateTxt(field1,field2)
  {  
    var field1 = document.getElementById(field1).value;  
    var field2 = document.getElementById(field2).value;  
    alert(field1 + '\n' + field2);

    }  ​
```

HTML:

```
<input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="Search by keyword" class="search_input" >
<select name="select" id="select" class="input_list" onkeyup="updateTxt('select','txt2');">
          <option>Search jobs by category</option>
          <option>Business Sales Leadership Development Program</option>
          <option>Business Sales Solutions</option>
          <option>CTO</option>
          <option>Call Center</option></select>
 <input name="button" type="button" class="btn" value="Go" onClick="updateTxt('select', 'textfield')">​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wx4Zg/)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to change the onClick to:

```
onclick="updateTxt('select','textfield');
```

because when you are using reserved words in JS it is not good - to say the least ;)
For full list of reseved words: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm
You can see there 'select'.

Btw, you might want to change the names to something better and avoid 'onClick' and JS inside your html.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not have an element with the id 'txt2'. Also try to use more explicit IDs, like 'myTextField' instead of 'select', it will make it easier to read and maintain your code.

Other than that, Amaan's answer should work.